# Accessing parent view of any view in android

Tags: android

I have a `TextInputEditText` inside a `TextInputLayout` in my xml code.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textfieldContainer2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:errorEnabled="true"
        app:errorTextAppearance="@style/customErrorTextColor"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/customHintTextAppearance"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textfieldContainer">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/bottomtextfield"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="add bottom text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**Problem**

I am trying to get `TextInputLayout` via `TextInputEditText` as shown below

```
TextInputLayout parentInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) textfield.getParent();
```

but this line of code throws `java.lang.IllegalStateException`

**Question**

What am I doing wrong here and how can I get parent `TextInputLayout` of any `TextInputEditText` through `TextInputEditText`'s reference.

**Stacktrace**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.yousafkhan.memegeneratorapp, PID: 10425
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
                      at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
                      at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
                      at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
                      at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                      at com.example.yousafkhan.memegeneratorapp.MainActivity.textFieldEmpty(MainActivity.java:64)
                      at com.example.yousafkhan.memegeneratorapp.MainActivity.createMeme(MainActivity.java:53)
```

Comment: whats the full java stacktrace?

Comment: @pskink posted.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting a reference to the `TextInputLayout` that contains the `TextInputEditText` can be done as the following:

```
TextInputEditText textfield = findViewById(R.id.bottomtextfield);
ViewGroup containingLayout = (ViewGroup) textfield.getParent();
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) containingLayout.getParent();
```

This is because `TextInputLayout` has a `FrameLayout` on it that contains the `TextInputEditText` associated.

Answer (score 1):

The view hierarchy in xml may not be same as the view herarchy returned by android. So getParent() may not return you the expected view.

Therefore you should prefer using :

```
TextInputLayout parentInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.textfieldContainer2);
```